# Unique_Ptr: Attemting To Reference A Deleted Function

Tags: c++, reference, move, unique-ptr

So I'm working on a school project right now in C++, although I'm not too familiar with the language yet.
The whole project is divided in several Milestones.
1: Reading a list with different Types of Creatures and storing them in a vector
2: Reading a TGA-File and storing it in a class.
...
5: Reading a TGA-Picture for every read Creature-Type and storing it for further use. (Printing on GUI, Remove/add)

So I thought it is a good idea to store the picture for each type in the class itself, as it should only be loaded once.
The load() function in my TGAPicture class will return std::unique_ptr so I added the type as an argument in my CreatureType class.
After doing that, I got several error like this:

```
Error   C2280   'biosim::CreatureType::CreatureType(const biosim::CreatureType &)': attempting to reference a deleted function  bio-sim-qt  E:\Development\C++\bio-sim-qt\bio-sim-qt\qtmain.cpp 58  1   

Error (active)      function "biosim::CreatureType::CreatureType(const biosim::CreatureType &)" (declared implicitly) cannot be referenced -- it is a deleted function  bio-sim-qt  e:\Development\C++\bio-sim-qt\bio-sim-qt\Model.cpp  15  26
```

So I read about 10 questions with similar titles like mine and every one pointed out, that you cant copy unique_ptr and suggested solutions like using std::move() or returning a reference.
Although I tried to use these to fix my problem, I wasn't able to do it in the slightest, probably because I'm pretty new to C++ and have never worked with unique pointers.

This is the code, that seems relevant to me:

```
/**
 * @class CreatureType
 * Object of the various CreatureTypes ingame
 */
class CreatureType {

    private:
    std::string name;
    int strengh;
    int speed;
    int lifespan;
    std::vector<std::string> attributes;
    std::string path;
    std::unique_ptr<TGAPicture> picture; //What I tried to add in order to stre my pictures

    public:
    CreatureType(const std::string& name
                , int strengh, int speed, int lifespan
                , const std::vector<std::string>& basic_strings
                , const std::string& path);

    /**
    * Initializes list with CreatureTypes by reading from a .txt-File
    */
    static CreatureList load(const std::string& file);

    /**
     * Printing Data in various ways
     */
    void getInfo() const;
    void getInfoInOneLine() const;

    std::string getName() const;
    int getStrengh() const;
    int getSpeed() const;
    int getLifespan() const;
    std::vector<std::string> getAttributes() const;
    std::string getPath() const;
};
```

}

```
CreatureType::CreatureType(const std::string& name
                            , int strengh, int speed, int lifespan
                            , const std::vector<std::string>& basic_strings
                            , const std::string& path)
    : name(name),
    strengh(strengh),
    speed(speed),
    lifespan(lifespan),
    attributes(basic_strings),
    path(path),
    picture(TGAPicture::loadPicture(Reference::PicturePath::creatureBasePath + path)){ }

/**
 * Implementation Notes:
 * - Does a line not fullfill the requirenments, it will be ignored
 * - @see <a href="https://elearning.uni-bayreuth.de/pluginfile.php/644828/mod_resource/content/2/Aufgabenblatt_1.pdf">Formation</a>
 * - Prints data with std::cout
 */
CreatureList CreatureType::load(const std::string& file) {
    CreatureList creatureList;
    std::ifstream fileStream; //Datei-Handle
    int lineNumber = 0;
    int correctLinesRead = 0;


    fileStream.open(file, std::ios::in);
    if (!fileStream.is_open()) {
        throw FileNotFoundException(file);
    }

    logger << INFO << "Einlesevorgang wird gestartet\n";

    //One line per loop
    while (!fileStream.eof()) {
        bool skipLine = false;

        std::string line;
        getline(fileStream, line);
        lineNumber++;

        ... //Checking if data is valid 


        //Every Parameter does exist and is valid
        creatureList.push_back(CreatureType(creatureArgs[0]
                                            , strengh, speed, lifespan
                                            , attributes, creatureArgs[5]));
        correctLinesRead++;
    }

return creatureList;
}
```

TGAPicture:

```
//no padding bytes
#pragma pack( push, 1 )
/**
 * @struct TGAHeader
 * Represents the standard TGA-Header.
 */
struct TGAHeader {
    char idLength;
    char colourmapType;
    char imagetype;

    short colourmapStart;
    short colourmapLength;
    char colourmapBits;

    short xOrigin;
    short yOrigin;
    short width;
    short height;
    char bits;
    char descriptor;

};
#pragma pack( pop )


/**
* @struct RGBA
* Represents a Pixel with a red, green, blue and possibly alpha value
*/
struct RGBA {
    std::uint8_t B, G, R, A;
};

/**
* @class TGAPicture
* Class used to represent TGA-Files, that are used in the program
*/
class TGAPicture {

    public:
    TGAPicture(const TGAPicture& other)
        : pixel(other.pixel),
        header(other.header),
        width(other.width),
        height(other.height),
        size(other.size),
        bitsPerPixel(other.bitsPerPixel) {}

    TGAPicture(TGAPicture&& other) noexcept
        : pixel(std::move(other.pixel)),
        header(std::move(other.header)),
        width(other.width),
        height(other.height),
        size(other.size),
        bitsPerPixel(other.bitsPerPixel) {}

    TGAPicture& operator=(const TGAPicture& other) {
        if (this == &other)
            return *this;
        pixel = other.pixel;
        header = other.header;
        width = other.width;
        height = other.height;
        size = other.size;
        bitsPerPixel = other.bitsPerPixel;
        return *this;
    }

    TGAPicture& operator=(TGAPicture&& other) noexcept {
        if (this == &other)
            return *this;
        pixel = std::move(other.pixel);
        header = std::move(other.header);
        width = other.width;
        height = other.height;
        size = other.size;
        bitsPerPixel = other.bitsPerPixel;
        return *this;
    }

    private:
    std::vector<RGBA> pixel; //Containes every pixel of the picture
    TGAHeader header;
    short width, height, size, bitsPerPixel;

    ...

    public:
    /**
    * Loads and initializes a picture to be used in the program
    * @throws TGAExpection if file could not be loaded
    */
    static std::unique_ptr<TGAPicture> loadPicture(const std::string& path);
    TGAPicture(const std::vector<RGBA>& pixel, const TGAHeader& header);
    ~TGAPicture();
    ....
};
}
#endif
```

cpp:

```
TGAPicture::TGAPicture(const std::vector<RGBA>& pixel, const TGAHeader& header)
    : pixel(pixel),
    header(header),
    width(header.width),
    height(header.height),
    size(header.width * header.height * (header.bits / 8)),
    bitsPerPixel(header.bits) { }



std::unique_ptr<TGAPicture> TGAPicture::loadPicture(const std::string& path) {
    ...


    for (int i = 0; i < header.height * header.width; i++) {
        pixel[i].B = *(bufferPosition++);
        pixel[i].G = *(bufferPosition++);
        pixel[i].R = *(bufferPosition++);
        pixel[i].A = (header.bits > 24 ? *(bufferPosition++) : 0xFF);
    }

    /**
     * Return unique_ptr
     * - ObjectFactory
     * - Automatic Deletion
     */
    return std::unique_ptr<TGAPicture>{new TGAPicture(pixel, header)};

}
```

And one class with an error would be:

```
class Model {

    public:
    explicit Model(const CreatureList& creatureList);
    ~Model();


    Terrain* getTerrain() const;
    CreatureList& getCreatureList();

    private:
    CreatureList creatureList;
    Terrain* terrain;

};


Model::Model(const CreatureList& creatureList) : creatureList(creatureList),
                                                terrain(new Terrain()) {

    for (CreatureType ty : creatureList) {  //line with errror
        ty.getInfoInOneLine();
    }
}
```

What do I need to change for it to work? And what would be the optimal way? Pretty sure that I'm supposed to use unique_ptr as return for the TGA::load() method.
I hope you can see through this mess and I'd like to apologize if my English isn't perfect, since it's not my first langugage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::unique_ptr` is not copyable.  It wouldn't be unique anymore if you could copy it.

You create *copies* of the elements in `creatureList` in your loop in `Model`'s constructor, but they have a non-copyable member, and so are non-copyable themselves by default.  If you don't actually need a copy of the elements, you should use references:

```
Model::Model(const CreatureList& creatureList)
    : creatureList(creatureList),
      terrain(new Terrain())
{
    for (CreatureType& ty : creatureList) {  // changed to reference instead
                                             // Note: this is still working with
                                             //       parameter, not the object's
                                             //       member.
        ty.getInfoInOneLine();
    }
}
```

You haven't actually provided a definition for `CreatureList`, but I suspect it also isn't copyable.  This means that `Model::Model`'s argument can't be copied into the object's member.  You have two options to fix this: make sure to move your `CreatureList` or make it copyable.

`std::unique_ptr` is movable, which means that `CreatureType` is by default as well, so you can do something like this:

```
Model::Model(CreatureList creatureList)  // Take by value now
    : creatureList(std::move(creatureList)),  // Move the parameter to the member
      terrain(new Terrain())
{
    for (CreatureType& ty : this->creatureList) {  // Use this-> to access member
                                                   // instead of now moved-from
                                                   // parameter.  You could also
                                                   // just change them to have
                                                   // different names.
        ty.getInfoInOneLine();
    }
}
```

This changes `Model`'s constructor to take its parameter by value and moves that value into the object's `creatureList` member.

If it makes sense, you could also make `CreatureType` copyable by adding an explicit copy constructor that copys the object pointed to by `picture`:

```
CreatureType::CreatureType(const CreatureType& other)
    : name(other.name),
      strengh(other.strengh),
      speed(other.speed),
      lifespan(other.lifespan),
      attributes(other.attributes),
      path(other.path),
      picture(new TGAPicture(*other.picture))
{
}
```

If you do that, the implicit move constructor will no longer be generated by the compiler, so you'll want to define that yourself:

```
CreatureType::CreatureType(CreatureType&& other)
    : name(std::move(other.name)),
      strengh(other.strengh),
      speed(other.speed),
      lifespan(other.lifespan),
      attributes(std::move(other.attributes)),
      path(std::move(other.path)),
      picture(std::move(other.picture))
{
}
```

There doesn't seem to be any reason for `TGAPicture::loadPicture` to return a `std::unique_ptr` though.  If you just return by value from that function you will avoid all of these problems:

```
TGAPicture TGAPicture::loadPicture(const std::string& path) {
    // ...
    return TGAPicture{pixel, header};
}
```

Comment: Oh I'm sorry the definition is: typedef std::vector<CreatureType> CreatureList;
Thanks for your in-depth answer!
So you'd advise me to change the return type of TGAPicture::loadPicture? We were told that a unique pointer should be used for ObjectFactory-methods like this one. Would you agree or disagree?

Comment: It looks like I would change a lot of things in order to support the version with unique pointers

Comment: @Awesome36 Only return by pointer if you have to.  If you're actually implementing a factory and it can return different concrete types then you have to return a pointer to the parent type.  In your case you only ever return one type though, so a pointer isn't necessary.  You're not saving any object copies: the returned value will either be optimized away or moved.